# Access to FB mailbox from Messenger platform

Tags: android, ios, facebook, api, messenger

Facebook removed access to the user's mailbox, well restricted it actually:

> This permission is granted to apps building a Facebook-branded client on platforms where Facebook is not already available. For example, Android and iOS apps will not be approved for this permission. In addition, Web, Desktop, in-car and TV apps will not be granted this permission.

Which for my purpose is pretty much the same thing. I'm currently looking into the new messenger app and wondering if someone knows if there is a way to have access to the text content from it.

What I'm trying to build is a translator app where a text message gets translated after sending it and before receiving it. Any help greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe in getting permission to my data. Set up a scraper and pull our data out of Facebook. Then do anything you want with it.

Comment: I hear you, but considering the application I think that won't last long with FB's ToS. Have you had any legal trouble with your approach?

Comment: Start with an app that allows users to automate their own browsers, in order to grab their data, in any way they want. Make it template driven so the community, and ultimately companies, can support the template, in the end, accessing the data through an API. Small companies become big by ignoring anything written anywhere they can't control. And as a man, I understand THAT data, IS mine.